# Usage of undefined extern variable with in the library is giving linker error in macOS

Tags: c++, clang++, macos-sierra

I am creating a dynamic library.

**foo.h**

```
extern unsigned int myoperator;
int operate(int a, int b);
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
int operate(int a, int b){
    switch(myoperator){
    case 0:
        return a+b;
    case 1:
        return a-b;
    default:
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

`libfoo` is built exceptionally well on linux gcc C++14, however its throwing  a linker error in macOS clang C++14. The error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_myoperator", referenced from:
      operate(int, int) in foo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The closest link to the issue I got on google is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html

I am not sure if the answer is in it.

Comment: 1. You need define it in `foo.cpp`. 2. Don't use name `operator` which is preserved.

Comment: Its not the exact code I've used. In my actual code I didn't use `operator`. Thank you

Comment: @songyuanyao If i define it in `foo.cpp` then I can't redefine it in the client. the above code got built in linux gcc

Answer (score 0):

If the "real" definition of 'myoperator' variable is in another file which is part of the same project foo belongs to, I think it should be better if you put the line code

```
extern unsigned int myoperator;
```

in your cpp file